# Is it possible to create this multicolumn flexbox layout using only css and media queries?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was wondering, if it is possible to build layouts like this two using only css and toggling between both layouts using media queries.

--

| A | B |

| C .... |

--

| A | B |

| A | C |

--

In v1 "A" and "B" get a width of 50% and "C" of 100%

In v2 "B" and "C" get a width of 50% and "A" gets a width and a height of "A + B"

Maybe something like this... ?

```
<div class="w">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
</div>

.w {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.a, .b { flex: 0 0 50%; }
.c { flex: 0 0 100%; }

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .a, .b, .c { flex: 0 0 50% }
    .b { margin-left: 50%; }
}
```

Comment: Provide a code sample and we'll help you.

Comment: Only if the container has a fixed/determinate height,

Comment: I just noticed the update you made. Now the explanation and the _letter layout_ doesn't match, so also update the _layout part_ with a more clear drawing of the two expected outputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this, where you toggle between `row` and `column` direction.

When in `column` direction, the `wrapper` will need a set height on the `wrapper`.

If to dynamically set the height when in `column` direction, Flexbox can't do that alone, so either need to use CSS Grid or add a small script that will adjust its height.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8wx9fxgh/3/)

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper > div {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper > div:last-child {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {    
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
  }  
  .wrapper > div:first-child {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .wrapper > div:last-child {
    flex-basis: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    A
  </div>
  <div>
    B
  </div>
  <div>
    C
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If one of either `A` or `B`/`C` can dictate the height, and the *other* should scroll its content, you can do like this, using absolute positioning on e.g. `A`

[Fiddle demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/8wx9fxgh/4/)

Stack snippet 2

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper > div {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper > div:last-child {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {    
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
  }  
  .wrapper > div:last-child {
    flex-basis: 0;
  }
  .wrapper > div:not(:first-child) {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 50%;
  }

  .wrapper > div:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 50%; bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A
  </div>
  <div>
    B<br>B<br>
  </div>
  <div>
    C
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not help me any further :(

Comment: @ToniProducto Maybe you could also explain why it doesn't do that? ... it does exactly what you asked for, and btw, I also changed the media query to `min-width`.